# Make somehow a binding between SeekBar and TextView

Tags: android

I add seekbar to my application - and next to this seekbar i want to add TextView that will show the value chosen on the seekbar.

Is it possible to do this binding only on the xml without doing it on the code behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeas its possible.. but you have to set the Textvalue Programmatically by implementing OnseekBarChangeListener add your seek bar and text View in Linear layout with horizontal orientation... and assign weight to seek bar and Text View according to you requirement.

Comment: ok ... so its not possible. 
i mean that i want to do it like microsoft doing it on WPF

Comment: i don't know what Microsoft doing.. but all i know is you have to do change text value programmatically.... you cannot do this through xml.